# Azure Vnet-to-Site Your VPN connectivity is impacted because the S2S VPN tunnels are disconnected

Tags: azure, vnet

[image: My problem picture]

I'm trying to do a azure Vnet to connect on-premise,

- my vpn is connected status on my local machine.
- I installed certificates and on local is working.
- *But my big problem is that on cloud between azure local network
  gateway and vnet gateway my status is displaying "Not conected"
  for those VPN.*

Some one can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the problem, first, try to [reset the Azure VPN gatewa](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/reset-gateway)y and reset the tunnel from the on-premises VPN device. If the problem persists, follow [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-troubleshoot-site-to-site-cannot-connect#troubleshooting-steps) to identify the cause of the problem.

Step 1. Check whether the on-premises VPN device is validated

Step 2. Verify the shared key

Step 3. Verify the VPN peer IPs

Step 4. Check UDR and NSGs on the gateway subnet

Step 5. Check the on-premises VPN device external interface address

Step 6. Verify that the subnets match exactly (Azure policy-based gateways)

Step 7. Verify the Azure gateway health probe

Step 8. Check whether the on-premises VPN device has the perfect forward secrecy feature enabled

Hope this could help you.